# How to plot two different color scales for two geom_points from two different dataframes in ggplot2?

Tags: ggplot2

I am trying to plot two datasets on the same graph. Both data are plotted using geom_point, and I want to separately represent the sizes and color by the z values.

```
x <- c(2,3,4,5)
y <- c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4)
z <- c(1,2,2,3)
x3 <- c(4,5,6,7)
y3 <- c(3.1,3.2,3.3,3.2)
z3<- c(1,2,3,4)
p1 <- data.frame(x=x,y=y,z=z)
p3 <- data.frame(x=x3,y=y3,z=z3)

s <- ggplot()+
geom_point(data= p1, aes(x=x,y=y, color=z, size=z))+
geom_point(data=p3, aes(x3,y=y3, color=z, size=z3))
```

How to I get continuous scale of colors and sizes separately to both geom_point? For example, z is scale_colour_gradient(low = "black", high = "red") and z3 is scale_colour_gradient(low = "light blue", high = "purple"). Similarly for sizes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easy ways would be with the `ggnewscale` package:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

x <- c(2,3,4,5)
y <- c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4)
z <- c(1,2,2,3)
x3 <- c(4,5,6,7)
y3 <- c(3.1,3.2,3.3,3.2)
z3<- c(1,2,3,4)
p1 <- data.frame(x=x,y=y,z=z)
p3 <- data.frame(x=x3,y=y3,z=z3)

s <- ggplot()+
  geom_point(data= p1, aes(x=x,y=y, color=z, size=z))+ 
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "black", high = "red") +
  new_scale_colour() + # Define scales before initiating a new one
  scale_size() +
  new_scale("size") +
  geom_point(data=p3, aes(x3,y=y3, color=z, size=z3)) +
  scale_colour_gradient(low = "dodgerblue", high = "purple") +
  scale_size()
s
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>